# Lombok: Data cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I have downloaded the Lombok.jar from the [official website](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse). I have double clicked on it and made sure it is installed on my **STS**. Then i have added the dependency into my `pom.xml`:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

and then i have the below class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Kinkester {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    int age;

}
```

but in the line `@Data` it complains with:

```
Data cannot be resolved to a type
```

So, it seems that it does not identify the lombok?

I have restarted my Eclipse, and cleaned the project, and updated the maven, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `lombok` jar instead of `lombok-maven`

Comment: additionally, you can find on the Project Lombok site exact dependency [Project Lombok Maven Dep](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven)

Answer (score 6):

That is the wrong import, what you want is,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted instead of the other one.